# Array statement to a method

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I want to calculate the weighted median of some number array x and its corresponding weight array w, the problem is I want to reduce the code with one method, but couldn't figure it out. So instead of many if-statements, it can be one method.

Here's an article that has an algorithm of this weighted median. [HERE](https://walkccc.github.io/CLRS/Chap09/Problems/9-2/)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int[] x = new int[] {3,4,6,10};
    int[] w = new int[] {1,2,3,5};
    int n = x.length;
    double sum = Arrays.stream(w).sum();

    System.out.println("Variable: "+Arrays.toString(x));
    System.out.println("Weight: "+Arrays.toString(w));

    if (n == 1) //if the array contains one element
        System.out.println("The weighted medain is: "+x[0]);

    else if (n == 2){ //if the array contains two elements
        if (w[0] >= w[1])
            System.out.println("The weighted medain is: "+x[0]);
        else 
            System.out.println("The weighted medain is: "+x[1]); 
    }

    else { 
        if ((w[0]/sum)+(w[1]/sum)+(w[2]/sum)>0.5){
            System.out.println("The weighted meadin is " + x[2]);
        }
        else if ((w[0]/sum)+(w[1]/sum)+(w[2]/sum)+(w[3]/sum)>0.5){
            System.out.println("The weighted meadin is " + x[3]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try switch statement...

Comment: Have you learned about **loops** yet? Use one.

Comment: Off topic but the sum of all elements in `w` should be 1

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Not needed if you calculate `w / sum(all w)`, which question code is doing.

Comment: Ah I see but now the code in the last else clause makes even less sense to me. Well, well.

Comment: @Andreas I know basic for loop, how could this will help?

Comment: @nimi0112 this won't reduce my code

Comment: @JoakimDanielson could you explain more?

Comment: The logic/code doesn't look anything like the page you linked to

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_median#Algorithm) summaries a solution pretty nicely: *Weighted median can be computed by sorting the set of numbers and finding the smallest numbers which sums to half the weight of total weight.* --- Sort the data (if not already sorted like your example is), calculate total weight (you did), then **iterate** from beginning (using loop), summing up the weights until you reach half the total, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need that precisely algorithm implemented, although I recommend you to try to do it yourself, I make my own version.

You must understand also that that algorithm just works for a set of numbers which the summation is equals to 1. Also its important to remember that the weigths must be equals to the numbers in that set. Considering that, this is one solution:

```
@Test
public void testName() throws Exception {
    final List<Double> xs = Arrays.asList(0.1, 0.35, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.05, 0.2);
    final List<Double> ws = Arrays.asList(0.1, 0.35, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.05, 0.2);

    final Double expected =
        IntStream.range(0, xs.size()).boxed().collect(toMap(i -> i, i -> xs.get(i) * ws.get(i))).entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey).map(xs::get).collect(toList()).get((int) Math.ceil(xs.size() / 2.) + 1);

    assertThat(getWeightedMedian(xs)).isEqualTo(expected);

}

private Double getWeightedMedian(final List<Double> xs) {
    final Double sum = xs.stream().collect(summingDouble(Double::doubleValue));
    if (sum != 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The sum of all values must be equals to one.");
    }

    final List<Double> xsDesc = xs.stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect(toList());
    Double sumLargest = 0.;
    for (final Double x : xsDesc) {
        if (sum - sumLargest - x < 0.5 && sumLargest - x <= 0.5) {
            return x;
        }

        sumLargest += x;
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The collection doesn't have an weighted median.");
}
```

Please observe that the expected value calculation is another way to get the 50th percentile of weighted set. This implementation does not impose sum equals to one or values equals to weights.